# Существует слово "храмосоздатель"?

Tags: лексика

*Но помимо своей агрессивной политики,  прославлен он и как щедрый **храмосоздатель**.*

Что делать с храмосоздателем (храмостроителем). Существуют такие слова? Или надо заменить словосочетанием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Ефремовой:
[храмостроитель](http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C), м. Строитель храма (1).

Слова "храмосоздатель" в словарях нет, но в давних произведениях оно все-таки встречается.

*Первый придѣлъ во имя священно-мученика Василія Херсонскаго и Татіаны мученицы, имена коихъ носятъ **храмосоздатель** и его супруга...* (И. Ф. Токмаков. Историко-статистическое и археологическое описание города Дмитрова с уездом и святынями [1893])

*Такъ поступалъ Даніилъ потому, что **храмосоздатель** Соломонъ, при самомъ освященіи храма, просилъ Господа внимать молитвамъ людей...* (Смолин Иоанн, диакон. Меч духовный в ограждение от сектантских лжеучений [1910])

У В. И. Даля в статье "воздвигать" есть слово **воздвижник** м., -ница ж. — воздвигающий, воздвигший что-либо. Мне кажется, что в Вашем тексте можно использовать слово [храмовоздвижник](https://books.google.ee/books?id=kA5oCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=NtHHLneoez&sig=ACfU3U16DiAmXqjDz6j5BawdSSgf__JHLw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJtcrg6pXnAhXnpIsKHaA7DEQQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false) ([Г. Д. Венус](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81,_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Зяблики в латах [1925]).

Comment: Римма, спасибо за помощь. Наверное, лучше использовать храмостроитель (или храмосоздатель  выделить курсивом).

Comment: Да, вполне возможно и курсивом, храмосоздатель — хорошее слово, не нарушающее, как мне кажется, словообразовательных правил. P. S. Спасибо Вам за вопрос — при ответе нашла для себя много новой информации.

Comment: Да, автор решит. Надеюсь на вашу помощь в подобных вопросах.

Answer (score 2):

Храмосозидатель — дал бы такое общее определение личности, причастной к возведению или восстановлению хотя бы даже одного храма.

Но есть слово ХРАМОЗДАТЕЛЬ ХРАМОЗДА́ТЕЛЬ, храмоздателя, муж. (книжн. торж. устар.). Создатель храма (см. храм в 1 знач.), тот, кто заботится о благосостоянии храмов. *Купец этот был большой храмоздатель.*

1. Создатель храма. Человек, который прилагает личные организаторские способности или личные средства для создания, строительства и благоукрашения православного храма.
   (Толковый словарь Ушакова)

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня современный текст примерно такого содержания:  «Почти всю свою жизнь он провел в военных походах – против татар, Болгарии, Византии, Венгрии… Но помимо своей агрессивной политики,  прославлен он  и как щедрый храмосоздатель. Он строит все новые и новые монастыри не только на своих, но и на новых, только что присоединенных землях, а также  в Византии, Греции…»    Может быть, посчитать его авторским неологизмом и дать курсивом?  Или что сделать?